# Pandas.read_csv issue

Tags: python, pandas

I trying to read the message from database, but under the class label can't really read same as CSV dataset.

> messages = pandas.read_csv('bitcoin_reddit.csv', delimiter='\t', 
>                              names=["title","class"]) 
>   print (messages)

[image: Under the class label the pandas only can read as NaN]

[image: The version of my CSV file]

Under the class label the pandas only can read as NaN

The version of my CSV file

```
title,url,timestamp,class
"It's official! 1 Bitcoin = $10,000 USD",https://v.redd.it/e7io27rdgt001,29/11/2017 17:25,0
The last 3 months in 47 seconds.,https://v.redd.it/typ8fdslz3e01,4/2/2018 18:42,0
It's over 9000!!!,https://i.imgur.com/jyoZGyW.gifv,26/11/2017 20:55,1
Everyone who's trading BTC right now,http://cdn.mutually.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/08-19.jpg,7/1/2018 12:38,1
I hope James is doing well,https://i.redd.it/h4ngqma643101.jpg,1/12/2017 1:50,1
Weeeeeeee!,https://i.redd.it/iwl7vz69cea01.gif,17/1/2018 1:13,0
Bitcoin.. The King,https://i.redd.it/4tl0oustqed01.jpg,1/2/2018 5:46,1
Nothing can increase by that much and still be a good investment.,https://i.imgur.com/oWePY7q.jpg,14/12/2017 0:02,1
"This is why I want bitcoin to hit $10,000",https://i.redd.it/fhzsxgcv9nyz.jpg,18/11/2017 18:25,1
Bitcoin Doesn't Give a Fuck.,https://v.redd.it/ty2y74gawug01,18/2/2018 15:19,-1
Working Hard or Hardly Working?,https://i.redd.it/c2o6204tvc301.jpg,12/12/2017 12:49,1
```

Comment: better if you can provide text version of your file not excel

Comment: Are you sure the delimiter is `tab`? You can try and omit the delimiter specification and let python auto-detect it

Comment: i have updated my text version file

Comment: Your delimiter is comma here. Also, it's `sep=`, not `delimiter=`.

Comment: looking at the excel file, the delimiter is `,`, also if you only want to extract title and class use `usecols=[0,3]`.

Comment: `delimiter=` is an alternative for `sep=` (as demonstrated in the question! ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separator in your csv file is a comma, not a tab. And since `,` is the default, there is no need to define it.

However, `names=` defines custom names for the columns. Your header already provides these names, so passing the column names you are interested in to `usecols` is all you need then:

```
>>> pd.read_csv(file, usecols=['title', 'class'])
                                               title  class
0             It's official! 1 Bitcoin = $10,000 USD      0
1                   The last 3 months in 47 seconds.      0
2                                  It's over 9000!!!      1
3               Everyone who's trading BTC right now      1
4                         I hope James is doing well      1
5                                         Weeeeeeee!      0
```